# Cannot click on links in nested div

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Having some trouble clicking on links in a nested DIV, from what I've found I need to set z-index somewhere but am having no luck getting it to work.  I've tried adding everything but the div id with the links to z-index: -1; and adding just the links div to z-index: 100.

HTML:

```
<div id="dots" align="center"><img src="dots_overlay.png"></div>
<div id="logo" align="center"><img src="logo.png"></div>
<div id="header" align="center">Service Links</div>
<div id="wrapper" align="center">
    <div id="left-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 1</div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="center-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 2</div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 3</div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper" align="center">
    <div id="left-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 4</div>
        <div id="clickables">Link</div>
    </div>
    <div id="center-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 5</div>
        <div id="clickables">Link</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 6</div>
        <div id="clickables">Link</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    background-image: url('background.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#dots {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#header {
    position:fixed;
    top:130px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:fff;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 150px;
}

#left-column {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

#center-column {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

#right-column {
    float: left;
    width:300px;
}

#titles {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #646464;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#clickables {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

If anyone could point out to me where I need to add my z-index that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add      to the end of the first wrapper.

Tested and it works.

Like that:

```
<div id="dots" align="center"><img src="dots_overlay.png"></div>
<div id="logo" align="center"><img src="logo.png"></div>
<div id="header" align="center">Service Links</div>
<div id="wrapper" align="center">
    <div id="left-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 1</div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="center-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 2</div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 3</div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
        <div id="clickables"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
    </div
    <div style="clear:both"></div><!-- This is what i added-->
</div>
<div id="wrapper" align="center">
    <div id="left-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 4</div>
        <div id="clickables">Link</div>
    </div>
    <div id="center-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 5</div>
        <div id="clickables">Link</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
        <div id="titles">Header 6</div>
        <div id="clickables">Link</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, be careful not to use the same IDs several times in the same page, they are supposed to be unique, best practice: use only class for CSS.

Then, even with a z-index of 100 (bad practice btw), the fixed elements will be above.
You probably don't need to have so many elements in the fixed, logo and dots might be better in the header element and only this one would be in `position: fixed`. So you could easily be sure that there is no link under the header that you couldn't click.

Then, you shouldn't need the `div` around each link, but you can use `ul>li` if you want.

I didn't want to provide you the real answer but more the understanding because he seems that it's what you currently need the most :)